# Extjs Windows closeAction 'destroy' not opening window

Tags: extjs, window, extjs6

I have an extJs window with closeAction: 'hide'

```
var myWin = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    ...
    closeAction:'hide',
    ...
});
```

I am opening this window on grid row doubleclick and it works well.

Now I want to change closeAction to 'destroy' for some reason.
But with closeAction 'destroy', the window opens for the first time I double click grid row but for second time it does not open. Again it opens if I double click grid row for third time.

Why this behaves in this way??
Am I doing anything wrong here or do I need to add anything else with closeAction 'destroy'.

Comment: Please show your code for the doubleclick action.

Answer (score 0):

closeAction destroys removes the window from DOM and hence you can't show it again. But I don't know why on 3rd click you see a window. Can you post the code where you create the window?

[extjs Window closeAction](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-closeAction)